# Monkey patching QWidget mousePressEvent not triggering QPushButton click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, monkeypatching, overriding

I would like to detect when a mouse click has been made on any QWidget and so I've tried monkey patching the mousePressEvent like so:

```
qwidgetmousepressevent = QtWidgets.QWidget.mousePressEvent
def overwriteQWidgetMousePressEvent(self, event):
    print("mouse press!")
    qwidgetmousepressevent(self, event)
QtWidgets.QWidget.mousePressEvent = overwriteQWidgetMousePressEvent
```

Which works fine on it's own, but fails to trigger the clicked signal of the QPushButton widget. I guess my question is, what are possible reasons for there to be any change of behavior to the program? As far as I can tell, I keep the same signature and call the same code but there is something causing a side-effect and I can't figure out what.

Comment: The code provided doesn't mention a button...did you forget to include something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QPushButton` class inherits `QAbstractButton`, which in turn inherits `QWidget`. If you monkey-patch the `QWidget` class, you are overriding `mousePressEvent` for every widget in your application. Is that really what you want to do?

The reason why the `clicked` signal is not emitted is because `mousePressEvent` is reimplemented by `QAbstractButton`, but your code never explicitly calls it. So the simple fix is to monkey-patch the `QAbstractButton` or `QPushButton` class instead of `QWidget`.

I don't know for sure why overriding `QWidget.mousePressEvent` bypasses the subclass implementations in PyQt. I guess that Python reimplemenations will always take precedence over the Qt ones, even though that may mean things seem to get called "out of order" (in terms of the logical chain of inheritance, that is).

Comment: Thanks, patching QAbstractButton does the job. I'm still confused why overriding QWidget was not enough, but will accept it as a reality of life for the moment :-/

Comment: @nqe. I thought I explained that pretty clearly. Your original patch doesn't call `QAbstractButton.mousePressEvent` (which is responsible for emitting the `clicked` signal) - all it does is call `QWidget.mousePressEvent`, which effectively does nothing.

Comment: Right. What I'm confused about is why overriding `QWidget.mousePressEvent` will break the behavior of `QAbstractButton.mousePressEvent`? As you say, the latter does not call the former, so why is there a cause and effect here? Actually in the code above, when I click on `QPushButton` I get two "mouse press!" messages, one for the button and one for the parent widget, but I can see that in the [C++ implementation](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp#L1092) the parent is never called, which is confusing to me as well.

Comment: @nqe. Any implementation on the Python side will override (i.e. completely bypass) all the Qt ones (no matter what the *logical* order of inheritance is). So nothing is in any way broken. Quite the opposite, in fact, because *nothing else gets called*. Only *one* implementation of `mousePressEvent` will ever get called, unless you explicitly call the base-class implementation yourself.

Comment: @nqe. As for your other question: the base-class implementation of `mousePressEvent` will call `event.ignore()`, which propagates the event to the parent. If you add `event.accept()` to the bottom of your patch, the event won't be propagated.

Comment: "Any implementation on the Python side will override (i.e. completely bypass) all the Qt ones (no matter what the logical order of inheritance is)"

So if I override `QWidget.mousePressEvent` I am bypassing the Qt implementation regardless of trying to store a pointer to its wrapper in line 1 and calling it in line 4? And that affects all related `mousePressEvent`s?

Btw, I make no claims on things broken, just trying to understand. I appreciate your efforts to explain!

Comment: Also, I see that I can check the instance of self and then call the appropriate method like:
```
    if isinstance(self, QtWidgets.QPushButton):
        QtWidgets.QPushButton.mousePressEvent(self, event)
```

So I guess I can use that as a workaround though I need to manually list all the instances I would like to use, but still better than deriving them.

Sorry one more question - Patching other methods like __init__ seems to work fine. Do you know what makes them different from the event method?

Comment: (1) As I said: Only *one* implementation of `mousePressEvent` will ever get called, *unless you explicitly call the base-class implementation yourself* (which you do,  via `qwidgetmousepressevent`). (2) The "event" methods (amongst others) are *virtual*, which means they can be called internally by Qt. The `__init__` method is Python-specific.